# Connection error in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET. My database is on another server which is called `DataServer`. The database server OS is Windows Server 2003 and it uses SQL Server 2008 R2. The problem is that when I start my computer and run the application for the first time it can't connect to the server and shows the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible

I open `My Computer` and type `\\DataServer` on the address bar of windows explorer and browse the server files. After doing this the problem disappears.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you added an explicit connection to your project, or are you relying on what you've typed in web.config or elsewhere for your connection string?

Comment: I'm relying on what I've typed in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

This may just be a name resolution problem - are you using a domain controller or is this in a workgroup? Are you on and off a VPN in order to connect to the server?

In any case, you can tell Visual Studio to connect to the IP address of `DataServer` instead of the name (either in the connection you've added to the project or the connection string explicitly specified in web.config). You can also add an entry to your hosts file that will supersede any DNS resolution.